# How setting immediate entry in long strategy Pine V5

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

I am building a small long strategy. The strategy buys on the close crossover on a predefined price level (Setting by line). My goal is to execute a long market order at the exact price and time of the crossover. I have tried several solutions, at the moment my script buys at the exact price but only executes the order on the next candle. Below I leave the code.

```
//@version=5
strategy(title = '', 
     overlay = true,
     calc_on_every_tick = true,
     initial_capital = 1000, 
     commission_type = strategy.commission.percent, 
     commission_value = 0.03, 
     pyramiding = 1, 
     default_qty_value = 100, 
     default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity,
     process_orders_on_close = false,
     close_entries_rule = 'ANY')

Line = input.price(0.00, "", group = "", confirm=true)
plot(Line)
Cond = ta.crossover(close, Line)

if Cond and strategy.position_size == 0
    strategy.entry(id = "BUY LONG", 
         direction = strategy.long,
             limit = Line,
             qty = 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

The strategy is calculated at the end of a candle.
The parameter "calc_on_every_tick" in the strategy declaration
recalculate on each chart update but only for the last candle.

If you change the timeframe for a lower one, ex :
tf 5 min will trigger the orders only every 5 min
and use request.security to do the calculation on an upper timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. calc_on_order_fills  = true
2. strategy.close(immediately=true)